# What are the pitfalls of combining a web site project with a web application project in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, vs-web-application-project

I have a web site project with a lot of files, it has become really slow to build. What I want to do is to create a web application project, and in **Explorer** add all the files to it, including the Bin folder. In Visual Studio I will not add these files (Show All Files will show them), only new files in one new folder that I am going to work on.

There are several assemblies in the original Bin folder that I need to reference in the web application project. Also, I will include the original web.config file.

So what way am I going to regret this in a few days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont have support for all the old stuff when using the Visual Studio Publish feature (I assume you wouldn't anyways).

I also would assume you wont have access to what is in your App_Code from your new web application project.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's one thing. You are right though, I don't use that feature.

Answer (score 1):

I will add an answer myself.

A rebuild in Visual Studio will clean out the bin folder...